# Max with left join in microsoft sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract from a database of an association, the name of the associate and its last paid share, but after a day trying I simply cannot extract that data.

The table senhas represents the shares, the table associados the associate data and senhas_associados, represents the shares paid by an associate, as it was a many to many relationship.

To query this, I'm trying to query the share with the maximum id (senha) which is in seassoc_senha_id in senhas_associados which represents a paid share.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Firstly, I've tried this statement, the output is the required, but it doesn't show associates who haven't paid any share which is needed (no records in senhas_associados):

```
SELECT assoc_nome, senha_desig
FROM associados, senhas, senhas_associados
WHERE assoc_id = seassoc_assoc_id 
AND seassoc_senha_id = senha_id
AND seassoc_senha_id IN (SELECT max(seassoc_senha_id)
FROM senhas, senhas_associados 
WHERE seassoc_senha_id = senha_id
AND seassoc_assoc_id = assoc_id)
```

Output:

```
assoc_nome   | senha_desig
------------------------------   
Carlos Costa | Maio
Rodrigo      | Abril
```

I've even tried adding this:

```
SELECT assoc_nome, senha_desig
FROM associados, senhas, senhas_associados
WHERE assoc_id = seassoc_assoc_id 
AND seassoc_senha_id = senha_id
AND seassoc_senha_id IN (SELECT max(seassoc_senha_id)
FROM senhas, senhas_associados 
WHERE seassoc_senha_id = senha_id
AND seassoc_assoc_id = assoc_id) OR senha_desig is null
```

To no avail, the output was the same.

Then, I've changed the "tactic" and went to left join:

```
SELECT assoc_nome, senha_desig
FROM associados
LEFT JOIN senhas_associados ON associados.assoc_id = senhas_associados.seassoc_assoc_id
LEFT JOIN senhas ON senhas.senha_id = senhas_associados.seassoc_senha_id
```

Output :

```
assoc_nome   | senha_desig
-------------------------    
Carlos Costa | Abril
Carlos Costa | Janeiro 
Carlos Costa | Fevereiro
Carlos Costa | Maio
Rodrigo      | Janeiro 
Rodrigo      | Fevereiro
Rodrigo      | Abril
Pedro Soares | NULL
```

Now it shows NULL's, but I can't find where to put the max function.

So I'm requesting your help, since today's afternoon that I'm stuck with this.

Thanks everyone,

Regards.

Here is the relational model of the involved tables: http://i44.tinypic.com/30aykv8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT max(senha_id),assoc_nome,senha_desig
    FROM associados a
    LEFT JOIN (senhas_associados sa
          LEFT JOIN senhas s
          on sa.senha_id = sa.seassoc_senha_id)
    ON a.assoc_id = seassoc_assoc_id
    GROUP BY assoc_nome,senha_desig
```

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks a lot Richard. Only changed the sa to s.

Comment: Also, is there a way to show senha_desig instead of senha_id?